# How to run jekyll locally and deploy on server with ease

Tags: jekyll, divshot

In my config file I have:

```
# Site domain name (for sitemap.txt generation)
url : http://development.adityaraj.divshot.io#http://adityaraj.com
url : http://localhost:4000
```

When I run the server locally all looks good, even after build the _site folder/index.html also works well. But when I deploy it to divshot it is still using my local urls for asset files, hence the styling and images are all missing.

Also I am using boilerplate theme from: http://prettystack.github.io/jekyll-blog-starter/

How do I config it to work correctly for both the locations. And I do not want to manually change it every time I deploy. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely it was a simple fix:

```
url : # just an empty setting takes care of this
```